# The format of ispell personal dictionary

Tags: ispell, flyspell

I'm having difficulty getting `flyspell` to accept a `personal dictionary`.

In my `.emacs` file I have the line:

```
(setq ispell-personal-dictionary "~/.karpov_dic")
```

This .karpov_dic file only has a few words such as:

```
Orionis
Virginis
```

The words are separated by `\n` characters. There's only one word per line, which is how I have seen ispell/aspell  customized dictionaries so far.

Yet, in Emacs, when I start

```
M-x flyspell-mode
```

I get this:

```
Error: The file "/home/karpov/.karpov_dic is not in the proper format.
```

Any clues?

Comment: The format of the personal dictionary depends on the back-end used (it could be either genuine Ispell, Aspell or Hunspell, maybe more). The program used can be found by examining the value of `ispell-program-name` variable. Here are instructions for creating a personal dictionary with Aspell: http://aspell.net/man-html/Creating-an-Individual-Word-List.html

Comment: Thanks! The program is aspell. But I don't quite get why it has to be so complicated. I've used aspell with text editors like gedit on Debian and Ubuntu (gnome, XFCE, etc.) and the personal dictionary is just a simple list of words which aspell accepts every time. I'm trying to figure out why it seems to be so different with Emacs.

Comment: Well, I think that the motivation for having a special dictionary format is, from the program perspective, that it will take less space and facilitate faster word lookup (looking up a word in a list would take time proportional to the length of a list, but structures like queues may offer logarithmic time, and hash-tables can do lookups in amortized constant time). Without knowing the details, I'd imagine that other editors run Aspell on the file supplied by the user to create a dictionary, but maybe there's more going on.

Comment: @wxvw The link you have indicated (aspell.net/man-html/Creating-an-Individual-Word-List.html), if I get it right, says that the dictionaries are  compiled and platform dependent. Having large personal dictionaries that I need to use, I guess I'll have to do the spellchecks out of Emacs :(  Except of course if I can find another spellcheck program for Emacs that accepts personal dictionaries like other text editors out there use.

Answer (score 5):

The error appears if you have an empty file or no file in place.
You need at least a header line in your dictionary file. 
following the format

personal_ws-1.1 *lang* num [encoding]

like

```
personal_ws-1.1 en 0
```

as described in [aspell documentation](http://aspell.net/man-html/Format-of-the-Personal-and-Replacement-Dictionaries.html)

See also:https://blog.samat.org/2008/11/02/creating-your-own-personal-aspell-dictionary/